# How to detect installed Chrome version from my Android Native App?

Tags: android, google-chrome

Is there any way to detect installed chrome version(like version 79, 80) from my Android Native App? I was searching and ask people around. but no one knows.

Please help me if you know about that.

Answer (score 0):

The best way thay i think is to search for the package of chrome.

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

where packageName is gonna be the chrome app.

Comment: Glad to help :)